# If I replace the hard drive on a Gateway GT5220 will system disc install OS

Tags: hard-drive, desktop-computer

The hard drive for this PC has failed and I want to replace it. However, I need to know if once I do that since there will not be a recovery partition on the new hard drive will the Gateway OS disc install on the new drive?

Answer (score 0):

It should install just fine.  My guess is the image on the discs will expand to fill the new hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a plain Microsoft OS re-installation disc, then no.

If it is some sort of proprietary Gateway "Restore" disc(s), then there is a possibility it will restore all partitions like it was when new, at least this is the way HP does it.